# how to properly render breakline with echo command?

Tags: bash, echo, github-actions

I am trying to use the GitHub action [create-file](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-file)

As part of my GitHub workflow I would like to create a text file like:

```
version=<version number>
released=<date>
```

where `<version number>` and `<date>` are variables previously defined in my script.

Hence, I tried the following:

```
FILE_DATA: "version=${{steps.read_version.outputs.value}}\nreleased=${{env.TODAY}}"
```

but `\n` is interpreted as space and not as a break line hence generated a single line file.

Looking at the source code of the GitHub action, it seems it only execute

```
 echo $FILE_DATA > "$FILE_NAME"
```

Where `$FILE_NAME"` is equals in my case to `./docs/version.properties`

Hence I tried to do what I wanted directly by using `echo` command instead of the GitHub action but whatever I tried it failed to properly render the `\n`.

Any suggestion would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to be a syntax issue.

```
    - name: Write multiline text to file
      shell: bash
      run: |
        {
          echo '$FILE_DATA'
        } >> $FILE_NAME
```

I had the same issue in my workflow file.
In [this](https://github.com/KevinRohn/github-full-release-data/blob/main/action.yml#L207) workflow file I also write multiple lines of text into a file.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Simply use `echo -e` and double quotes... .

```
#!/bin/bash

version="1.1"
released="01-10-2022"

myString1="version=$version\nreleased=$released"

echo -e "$myString1" > test1.txt
```

Output:

```
version=1.1
released=01-10-2022
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to directly use : 
`echo version=${{steps.read_version.outputs.value}}\nreleased=${{env.TODAY}}` ?

Comment: yes use `echo -e "version=${{steps.read_version.outputs.value}}\nreleased=${{env.TODAY}}"`

Comment: works like a charm .... thank you  !

Comment: You are welcome!